# How to combine two SQL queries with different ORDER BY clauses

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, sql-order-by

I looked online, but I could only find two queries combined with the **same** `order by`.

First query:

```
SELECT
  Name
  , Priority
FROM Music
WHERE `Priority` > 0 AND `date` > '2014-10-27 20:04:25'
ORDER BY `Priority` DESC
```

Second query:

```
SELECT
  Name
  , Priority
FROM Music
WHERE `Priority` = 0 AND `date` > '2014-10-27 20:04:25'
ORDER BY `date`
```

I need to combine the first and the second query into one, where the first query is executed and then the second query is executed giving me a complete list.

Comment: order by `date`,`Priority` DESC

Comment: @iamde_coder: Apart from the fact, this is probably intended to read `ORDER BY priority DESC, date`: This would apply the `BY date` -specific to the second query- to the first query's result as well. With OP explicitely pointing at the different sort criteria, this might not deliver, what is being asked for - for whatever reason. Whether or not it actually makes a difference, does -of course- depend on the real data.

Answer (score 7):

You could use the `union all` operator. Unfortunately, `union [all]` does not allow applying an `order by` clause to each query, so some trickery is required. For instance, you can "hide" the `order by` clause inside a subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT   Name, Priority 
        FROM     Music 
        WHERE    `Priority` > 0 AND `date` > '2014-10-27 20:04:25' 
        ORDER BY `Priority` DESC) t
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT   Name, Priority
        FROM     Music
        WHERE    `Priority` = 0 AND `date` > '2014-10-27 20:04:25'
        ORDER BY `date`) s
```

Comment: Note that MySQL doesn't guarantee the order that the outer query will return rows in; we observe consistent behavior, but it's not a guarantee. MySQL does allow an ORDER BY with an implicit UNION ALL operation, e.g. `(SELECT ... ) UNION ALL (SELECT ... ) ORDER BY 2 DESC, 1`.  But why use two queries at all in this case, since we're guaranteed that there's no overlap.

Answer (score 6):

Is it not just 1 query... Where Priority is both > or = 0

```
select Name, Priority 
from Music 
where `Priority` >= 0 
AND `date` > '2014-10-27 20:04:25' 
order by `Priority` DESC, `date`
```

Answer (score 4):

Whilst combining `priority > 0` and `priority = 0` into `priority >= 0` seems fair, the sort order for the second query **must** -strictly speaking- **not** be applied to the data retrieved by the first one. With no detailed information on the actual data, it's hard to tell whether it makes a difference. However, in case of doubt (and as OP does explicitly point out the fact), I'd go for

```
SELECT
  name
  , priority
FROM MUSIC
WHERE priority >= 0
  AND date > '2014-10-27 20:04:25'
ORDER BY priority DESC, CASE priority WHEN 0 THEN date END
;
```

I tested against @Spock's result with some fake data, and do actually get a different result:
[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/39bf8/1)

#### Update 2015-08-08

To address the general problem at a slightly wider scale, let's suppose some `WHERE` conditions, which are not as easily combined into a single one:

```
SELECT
  name
  , priority
  , date
FROM MUSIC
WHERE priority > 1
  AND date > '2014-10-27 20:04:25'
ORDER BY priority DESC, date DESC
;

SELECT
  name
  , priority
  , date
FROM MUSIC
WHERE priority <= 1
  AND date < '2014-10-26 00:00:00'
ORDER BY date
;
```

This could be addressed along:

```
SELECT
  name
  , priority
  , date
FROM
  (SELECT
    1 resultSet
    , name
    , priority
    , date
  FROM MUSIC
  WHERE priority > 1
    AND date > '2014-10-27 20:04:25'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    2 resultSet
    , name
    , priority
    , date
  FROM MUSIC
  WHERE priority <= 1
    AND date < '2014-10-26 00:00:00'
  ) T
ORDER BY resultSet,
  CASE resultSet
  WHEN 1 THEN priority
  END DESC,
  CASE resultSet
  WHEN 1 THEN date
  END DESC,
  CASE resultSet
  WHEN 2 THEN date
  END
;
```

So we introduce `resultSet` to get a handle on each of them, and specify specific sort criteria.

See it in action: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8c316/1)
Please comment, if and as this requires adjustment / further detail.