# MYSQL SELECT MAX from two columns

Tags: mysql, max

I have a table with columns:

```
col1  col2  col3  col4  entryId
1     2     abc   123   1
4     1     abc   234   2
4     2     abc   234   3
2     1     abc   456   4
2     2     abc   456   5
1     2     qwe   567   6
4     1     qwe   678   7
5     2     qwe   789   8
```

I need a mysql query to check for a given col4 value. If it is found, return the row with the largest col2. If none is found, return the row with the largest col 1 (then largest col2) for a given col3 (abc).

Example:

If searching for col4 = 456 AND col3 = abc, output would be: 2, 2, abc, 456, 4

If searching for col4 = 891 AND col3 = abc, output would be: 4, 2, abc, 234, 3

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by 'for a given col3 (abc)', please?

Comment: I will always know the col3 value so it should be in the WHERE statement.

Comment: col4=891 is not shown in the sample data, can you either add the data for it, or provide other sample outputs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `ORDER BY`.

Run `SELECT * FROM table WHERE col4 = 456 AND col3 = 'abc' ORDER BY col2 DESC LIMIT 1`. If no record is found, then run `SELECT * FROM table WHERE col3 = 'abc' ORDER BY col1 DESC, col2 DESC LIMIT 1`.

Edit: Should you want to do it using just one SQL query, you can combine those two using `UNION ALL` as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27931257/how-to-combine-two-sql-queries-with-different-order-by-clauses).

Comment: I just ran a test, however it is returning col1 value 99 always. I assume this has to do with the column data type VARCHAR instead of INT. Can you ORDER BY a VARCHAR?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table where EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table WHERE col4 = @col4 ) AND 
col4 = @col4 ORDER BY col2 DESC LIMIT 1

SELECT * FROM table where NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table WHERE col4 = @col4 ) 
AND col4 = @col4 ORDER BY col1 DESC, col2 DESC LIMIT 1
```

Hope, It works